# more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found

Tags: wcf

I have a question about my soap services(wcf)
I implement my wcf service and all the function implement correctly at compile time
I do not have any compile time error but when i run my code I received this error message

> An endpoint configuration section for contract 'test.ICore' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration

I think in soap services we need some change in web.config file
another point is that my project have multiple soap services.
may it cause a problem?

how can i solve this issue?
thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is because of you have a multiple endpoint with the same address in your web.config file
like that

```
<binding name="TestSoap">
          <security mode="Transport" />
</binding>
<binding name="TestSoap" />


<endpoint address="http://TestSoap/Core.svc/soap"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Soap" contract="TestSoap.ICore"
            name="TestSoap" />
<endpoint address="https://TestSoap/Core.svc/soap"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TestSoap"
            contract="TestSoap.ICore" name="TestSoap" />
```

you can use this example for your code.

I hople you can solve your problem

Comment: For those that might run into this like I did. I had a very similar problem . Except it was the app.config file in my client code that was corrupted when I migrated my web service from Windows Server 2012 R2 to Windows Server 2022.

Answer (score 0):

In general, an interface contract can be supported by multiple endpoints, but bindings and addresses can vary, such as this:

Server-side:

```
<service
    name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService"
    behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
  <endpoint address=""
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />
  <endpoint address="secure"
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />
</service>
```

Client-side:

```
<client>
  <endpoint name="basic"
            address="http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />

  <endpoint name="secure"
            address="http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc/secure"
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />
</client>
```

In the call:

```
CalculatorClient client = new CalculatorClient("basic");
Console.WriteLine("Communicate with basic endpoint.");

client = new CalculatorClient("secure");
Console.WriteLine("Communicate with secure endpoint.");
```

Feel free to contact me if have any issues.